# Make variables persist across instances of a script

Tags: shell, sh

I'm writing a script to toggle a program and need a way to make sh remember a variable after the script has executed and terminated. The only way I can think is by writing a daemon, but there must be a simpler way.

The code works when run in a persistent session, but cannot work as I intend it; the exported variables are deleted when the script finishes running.

I need a toggle as I'm planning to bind the script to a key to toggle japanese and english input, and need to switch between them.

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
export toggle=0
if [ $toggle = 0 ];
then
        test -z $(pgrep wlanthy) && wlanthy & disown;
        export toggle=1;
elif [ $toggle = 1 ];
then
        test $(pgrep wlanthy) && killall wlanthy
        export toggle=0
else echo error
fi
```

the problem was solved simply by doing this. I was overthinking it:

```
#!/bin/sh
if test -z $(pgrep wlanthy);
then
    wlanthy & disown;
    exit
elif test $(pgrep wlanthy);
then
    killall wlanthy
    exit
else echo error
fi
```

This script is bound to a single key that toggles an IME (an input method engine, which turns english keyboard text into japanese.) , meaning the script needs to both start and stop the program, hence its behaviour.
For example, press the key -> type some japanese -> press the key again -> type some english.

Comment: You're going to *have to* save the value somewhere; a daemon is one way, writing to a file is another way. Since it's a toggle you could use the presence or absence of a file (or a directory) to indicate state, without having to actually write any data. e.g. if directory ~/.myscript-toggle/ exists the value of your var `toggle` is 1, if absent the value is 0

Comment: The only way to save state is the file system. But I think the concept of a script that has different behavior on every even or odd call is strange. Please [edit] your question and add more background information about your use case. Why do you need this toggling? Why don't you use different "start" and "stop" scripts or a command line argument to distinguish the two cases. If something goes wrong, the behavior of your script and the caller's expectations might get out of sync.

Comment: In general, if you're starting and stopping a service, you should use your OS vendor's tools for the purpose -- typically, on modern Linux, systemd (or launchd on MacOS; if you're designing your own embedded system you have lots of great choices, such as s6 or [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) or others). Create `wlanthy.service` and then you can use `systemctl is-active wlanthy` to see if it's up and decide if you want to do a `systemctl start wlanthy` or `systemctl stop wlanthy`, etc.

Comment: @StephenP Thanks, this helps, I'll update the question once I've written the script to use a file.

Comment: @Jemsurfer It is still not clear why you want this approach. Now your script startts the daemon if it is not already running or kills it if it it running. So normally every odd call should start it, every even call should kill it: start - kill - start - kill etc. I consider this a strange user interface. If something goes wrong, the script may behave different. Example: The daemon is started in the first execution of your script. If the daemon terminates unexpectedly, the second execution will not terminate it but start it again, the third execution will kill it: start - start - kill

Comment: @Bodo the daemon that this script is for is an IME; it serves to interpret keyboard input into Japanese characters. That means I need to be able to turn it on and off, to switch from English to Japanese and vice versa. If it crashes, no problem; press the key binded to this script and it starts again. The odd-even behaviour isn't really necessary, and this is a much simpler implementation for the behaviour that I need than using file writing; *it's only a toggle*.

Comment: @Jemsurfer All information should be added to the question, and in general you should not edit the solution into the question. (You could have written an answer when the question was not yet closed.) Maybe I did not make myself clear. My question was why you need the same script to start or stop the daemon instead of two separate start and stop scripts. From your explanation I can guess that you might want to bind this script to a key (or key combination) and you want the same key (combination) to toggle the input method.

Comment: Yes, the script is binded to a key; XF86Keyboard, which both toggles it on an off, meaning a single script for both functions is neccesary. I'll add this detail to the question now.